# how can I set the strings inside a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data with **n** number of columns. The first column is strings and the others are values.

As an example, one df can be found below

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
5L), .Label = c("Ajngs ", "HAUDD;HHEYDG", "hdgdhdgh", "hdgduk;ldodjg", 
"hdhzd;hftfgd", "Kuksjgd", "sjsggd;pfofjdg", "Tmlsks", "yhfkfu"
), class = "factor"), A1 = c(6197300L, 54415000L, 18671000L, 
22473000L, 3922800L, 2137900L, 180210000L, 5053000L, 0L), A2 = c(3701100L, 
33892000L, 11169000L, 18095000L, 2734200L, 1423600L, 113860000L, 
3231300L, 0L), B1 = c(2496200L, 20523000L, 7502400L, 4378400L, 
0L, 714310L, 66351000L, 1821700L, 0L), B2 = c(1124900L, 18487000L, 
9858100L, 4413400L, 0L, 2137900L, 80461000L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", 
"A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

What am I trying to do is: each two columns are together (in this example A1 and A2 are together , B1 and B2 are together)

So, I want to check if A1 is almost double (**means 50% one value bigger than the other one**) of A2 paste the corresponding string instead the value, if the A2 is double of A1 paste the corresponding string instead the value. if they are not double lager than the other, set it to NAN

As an example

```
          A1        A2
Ajngs   6197300   3701100
```

A1 is almost double of A2 so the output should look like this

```
        A1        A2
Ajngs  Ajngs     NAN
```

The expected output

```
          A1    A2     B1       B2
Ajngs   Ajngs   NAN   Ajngs     NAN
Kuksjgd Kuksjgd NAN    NAN      NAN
Tmlsks    NAN   NAN    NAN      NAN
yhfkfu    NAN   NAN    NAN      NAN
hdgduk;ldodjg   NAN NAN NAN NAN
sjsggd;pfofjdg  sjsggd;pfofjdg  NAN NAN sjsggd;pfofjdg
HAUDD;HHEYDG    HAUDD;HHEYDG    NAN NAN NAN
hdgdhdgh    NAN  NAN    hdgdhdgh    NAN
hdhzd;hftfgd    NAN NAN NAN NAN
```

Comment: Please show the full expected output for the input dataset

Comment: What threshold do you set for a value being "almost double"? And do you want to set the other to `NaN` (Not a Number) or `NA` (missing value)?

Comment: I don't think you mean strings... strings are characters, but all your columns are integers

Comment: Your output wrong for 75%. First row, 3701100 is 59% of 6197300, so it should be NaN, but in your output it would look that still qualifies as "almost double"?

Comment: @Amit Kohli thanks I modified my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the corrected code below. Just change the value of almostDouble to your liking. This accepts more than 4 columns of dataframe.

```
df <- structure(list(X = structure(c(1L, 6L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
5L), .Label = c("Ajngs ", "HAUDD;HHEYDG", "hdgdhdgh", "hdgduk;ldodjg", 
"hdhzd;hftfgd", "Kuksjgd", "sjsggd;pfofjdg", "Tmlsks", "yhfkfu"
), class = "factor"), A1 = c(6197300L, 54415000L, 18671000L, 
22473000L, 3922800L, 2137900L, 180210000L, 5053000L, 0L), A2 = c(3701100L, 
33892000L, 11169000L, 18095000L, 2734200L, 1423600L, 113860000L, 
3231300L, 0L), B1 = c(2496200L, 20523000L, 7502400L, 4378400L, 
0L, 714310L, 66351000L, 1821700L, 0L), B2 = c(1124900L, 18487000L, 
9858100L, 4413400L, 0L, 2137900L, 80461000L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("X", 
"A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))

new.df <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x){
    almostDouble <- 1.5
    for(i in seq(from = 2, to = length(x), by = 2)){
        if(as.numeric(x[i]) > (almostDouble * as.numeric(x[i+1]))){
            x[i] <- x[1]
            x[i+1] <- "NAN"
        }
        else if(as.numeric(x[i+1]) > (almostDouble * as.numeric(x[i]))){
            x[i+1] <- x[1]
            x[i] <- "NAN"
        }
        else
            x[i] <- x[i+1] <- "NAN"
    }
    return(x)
})

new.df <- t(new.df)
new.df <- as.data.frame(new.df)
```

Comment: thanks , i understand the code ! thanks, I have only one doubt, is it working for when I have more than 4 columns of integer values ?

Comment: The corrected code will not work with more than 4 columns.

Comment: The corrected code will *now work with more than 4 columns.